# When I click logout from overflow menu it should go MainActivity to LoginActivity but it opens same MainActivity I tried all ways

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.action_logout:
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            break;
        case R.id.action_contacts:
            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddContact.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

When I click logout from overflow menu it should go MainActivity to LoginActivity but it opens same MainActivity .
Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Am guessing you are trying to close all the activities in the back stack. try this code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

this will clear all the previously opened activities and start you LoginActivity.